# Match everything between double quotes, multiple capture groups

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to leverage regex to extract information that exists between double quotes in every line of a configuration file. I'm okay with some basic level regex, but when it comes to complex ones; especially involving capture groups I keep running into brick walls despite trying to test and research via [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com).

```
my $text = '
"Key1" = { StuffIDontCareAbout = "Value1" },
"Key2" = { StuffIDontCareAbout = "Value2" },
"Key3" = { StuffIDontCareAbout = "Value3" },
"Key4" = { StuffIDontCareAbout = "Value4" },';
my %hash = undef;
for (split/\n/,$text) {
  my $pattern = qr/(")(?:(?=\\?))\2.)*?\1/;
  $hash{$1} = $2 if (/$pattern/);
}
print Dumper \%hash;
```

On [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) the information I care about is highlighted; however in my perl script $1 = " & $2 = null.

I think I need to match quotes with non-capture groups so that the first and second capture group is everything between them, however I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can there (_ever_) be nested quotes?  "Like "this" case?"  If not, then you can match: a quote, any number of non-quote chars (capture that), then quote -- repeatedly. Like: `/"([^"]+)"/g`

Comment: @anubhava I expect that the perl %hash is populated with Key1 = Value1, etc. It seems as though perls $1 & $2 variables return the capture groups instead of the matches.

Comment: @zdim, I have not seen nested quotes, the config file seems to have a standard syntax.

Comment: OK, thanks; I expected that (posted an answer)

Comment: @zdim That regex only returns 1 capture group, so it will populate the $hash{$1} variable, but not the = $2 variable. The trick is getting the matches to be referenced in the capture groups I think.

Comment: Cleaned up some typos, tested.  The regex returns what you need -- the content between all pairs of quotes, two in this case.  It parses your example as expected (now it does!)

Comment: (edited a little more, added another way as a demo, tested again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there can *never* be nested quotes, never ever, then you can match a sequence of non-quote characters between quotes, and do that "globally" (`/g` modifier), so all such instances in the string. One way

```
my %hash;

foreach my $line (split /\n/, $text) {
    if (my ($key, $value) = $line =~ /"([^"]+)"/g) {
        $hash{$key} = $value;
    }
}
```

There are a number of other ways to check that you got two (and precisely two?) matches, and to organize the rest of the processing.<sup>†</sup>

Note that there is no need for `undef` to be assigned to a variable when it is declared, and it doesn't do anything; a new `my` variable (unassigned) *is* `undef`.

All code tested with `$text` copied verbatim from the question.

---

<sup>†</sup> As a curiosity, can do it all in one line

```
my %hash = map { /"([^"]+)"/g } split /\n/, $text;
```

This isn't a good practice, for one since we can't check anything along the way.